# Problem with Flutter Drift DAO when calling method to fetch data, problem is the context i use for calling method from dao to fetch data

Tags: flutter, dart, build, dao, drift

Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this AddUser Widget
This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider

```
- You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.
  To fix, perform a hot-restart.
```

- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.

```
  Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
  other routes will not be able to access that provider.
```

- You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.

```
  Make sure that AddUser is under your MultiProvider/Provider<UserTableDao>.
  This usually happens when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.
```

This one is my debug console result

`

```
  @override
  Widget build(
    BuildContext context,
  ) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        flexibleSpace: const Image(
          image: AssetImage('assets/images/slow-motion.gif'),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
        title: const Text('Χρηστες'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                addUserDetails(context);
              },
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.save,
              ))
        ],
      ),
```

`

```
void addUserDetails(BuildContext newcontext) {
    final userEntity = UserTableCompanion(
      id: drift.Value(widget.counter),
      userName: drift.Value(usernameController.text),
      password: drift.Value(passwrodContoller.text),
      email: drift.Value(emailControler.text),
      name: drift.Value(nameController.text),
    );
    // Provider.of<AppDb>(context, listen: false).insertUsers(userEntity);
    final dao = Provider.of<UserTableDao>(newcontext, listen: false);
    dao.insertUsers(userEntity);
```

this is my method and where i call it

I already have the dao functions, i get the data to insert it
I know what my problem is but i find it difficult to solve it
It has something to do with the context i use and where i get it from